# Is hiding all rows of duplicated data possible?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am building a report using a SQL Stored Parameter that I created. It pulls data that may have 1 line per unique number, or 2 lines per unique number. I want to only show rows where there is only 1 line.

I have tried changing visibility, but the closest I have come to is

```
=IIF(Fields!uniquenumber.Value = previous(Fields!uniquenumber.value,True,False)
```

but this hides 1 of the rows, and not both. I have also tried using CASE WHEN in the query to identify if there are more than 1 line, but I still haven't been able to hide when there is more than 1 line. My query is below (redacted quite a few lines of extra criteria that aren't relevant to my question here. There are quite a few instances where the first part of my WHERE statement will have data that also meets the criteria of the 2nd part.

```
SELECT
    Reorders.LastRxNo,
    Reorders_1.LastRxNo AS Reorders1LastRxNo,
    Rxs_2.RxBatch AS Rxs2RxBatch,
    Reorders.FacID,
    KeyIdentifiers.GPI,
    Reorders.LastFillDt,
    Rxs_1.RxBatch as Rxs1RxBatch,
    CASE 
        WHEN (Reorders.LastRxNo<>Reorders_1.LastRxNo) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS Duplicate

FROM Reorders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Rxs AS Rxs_1
    ON Reorders.LastRXNo = Rxs_1.RxNo
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN KeyIdentifiers
    ON Reorders.NDC = KeyIdentifiers.NDC
  INNER JOIN Patients
    ON Reorders.FacID = Patients.FacID
    AND Reorders.PatID = Patients.PatID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Reorders AS Reorders_1
    ON Reorders.FacID = Reorders_1.FacID
    AND Reorders.PatID = Reorders_1.PatID
    AND KeyIdentifiers.NDC = Reorders_1.NDC
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Rxs AS Rxs_2
    ON Reorders_1.LastRxNo = Rxs_2.RxNo

WHERE       
        Reorders.ProfileOnly = 1
    AND Rxs_1.RxBatch IS NULL
    AND Reorders.CutOffDt IS NULL
    AND Reorders.PackType LIKE 'PHDEF%'
    AND Reorders.Auto = 1
    AND Reorders.PhRxStatus IS NULL
    AND Reorders.LastFillDt > '01/01/2019'
    AND (Reorders.LastRxNo = Reorders_1.LastRxNo
         OR Reorders.LastRxNo <> Reorders_1.LastRxNo AND Rxs_2.RxBatch IN ('CF','GONE'))

ORDER BY Reorders.FacID, Patients.PatLName, Patients.PatFName
```

Yields Results Similar to:

```
LastRxNo     Reorders1LastRxNo     Rxs2RxBatch    Duplicate             
111          111                   null            0
222          222                   null            0
222          444                   CF              1
```

In the above example, I only need to see the lines like line 1. Since "LastRxNo" 222 has 2 lines, I do not want to see it on my final report. (However, it is queried, because when LastRxNo =222 AND Reorders1LastRxNo = 222 and Rxs2RxBatch IS NULL would pull if I didn't account for it in my WHERE statement, I think. I am happy doing this any way possible, whether it be in the query or in SSRS report.

Comment: As it is, this query seems invalid. Table alias `Reorders_1` is used in the query but not defined. Same problem for `Rxs_2`. Is this really the query that you are using?

Comment: I would add a distinct clause to your select statement and amend your where clause and remove "(Reorders.LastRxNo = Reorders_1.LastRxNo
OR Reorders.LastRxNo <> Reorders_1.LastRxNo" as these cancel each other out

Comment: what version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB that is not my full query. As I stated in my OG post, I redacted many lines that weren't relevant to the question. Those tables are present in my joins and defined there.

Comment: @SuperSimmers44 Well, the where clause you see is not what I had originally. GMB edited my original post and moved some parentheses, which is not what I have. My where clause is (Reorders.LastRxNo=Reorders_1.LastRxNo OR Reorders.LastRxNo<>Reorders_1.LastRxNo AND Rxs_2.RxBatch IN ('CF','GONE'))   Moving the parenthesis mattered in this case, as they don't cancel each other out. (I changed my query back to what I had originally in the original post)

Comment: @AlanSchofield I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: I changed the query to include the rest of it (including joins and more parts of the WHERE clause, to help illuminate more of what I am grabbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your CASE ... as duplicate with

```
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LastRxNo) AS LastRxNoCount
```

then

wrap the whole query in another select like this...

```
SELECT * FROM 
            (
            your original query here including the change stated above
             ) q
         WHERE q.LastRxNoCount =1
```

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out all rows where the number of rows is greater than 1:

```
SELECT LastRxNo, RxBatch
FROM Reorders
WHERE RxBatch IN ('CF','GONE')
AND Reorders.LastRxNo IN
    (SELECT LastRxNo FROM Reorders GROUP BY LastRxNo HAVING COUNT(LastRxNo) = 1)
```

You should just be able to add the last two lines into your WHERE clause.

Alternatively, you could add it to your JOIN conditions:

```
SELECT
Reorders.LastRxNo
FROM Reorders
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT LastRxNo FROM Reorders 
    GROUP BY LastRxNo 
    HAVING COUNT(LastRxNo) = 1
) AS UniqueRxNo ON UniqueRxNo.LastRxNo = Reorders.LastRxNo
```

Comment: I added this, but it didn't make any change to my results. I did change the code above, may help show why this wouldn't work?

Comment: You should just be able to add the last two lines into your WHERE clause and it will work. Alternatively, put it in your JOIN conditions as edited in above.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it one of 2 ways:

1. is in your data source, do a distinct select.
2. Set the "Hide Duplicates"  property on the detail line in the report properties

Comment: I don't understand why, but when I add "DISTINCT" to the Select statement (For LastRxNo), I still get the same results as my yields in the original post.  And Hide Duplicates doesn't work, because it only hides the duplicate, not the first line, also. I want to hide both lines.

Comment: You are obviously selecting more columns than you are displaying on the report.  Show the full dataset or do a select distinct and remove the column that is not a duplicate ..

Comment: DISTINCT won't work for this use case - DISTINCT shows one row when there are duplicates whereas OP wants to only show rows that have no duplicates. The same applies to "Hide Duplicates"